# Change sort arrow position in flex grid

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex-mx

Currently when sorting in a flex grid, the sort arrow that shows whether the column is sorted ascending or descending is right aligned to the column. Is there anyway to change the position of the sort arrow, such as applying padding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would probably have to extend the `DataGridHeader` class and override the `placeSortArrow()` method.